# Conditional convergence of $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$?

Tags: conditional-convergence

What's a simple way to display $$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$$ conditionally convergent (i.e. convergent, but not absolutely)?

Comment: Integration by parts, with $u=\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: To show it isn't absolutely convergent, maybe you could approximate it by triangular areas beneath and use a comparison test. That may be algebraically complicated, but conceptually simple.

Comment: For that part I think I would just use the fact that $|sin(x)| \ge \frac{1}{2}$ periodically often.

Comment: @Did It's clearly not the same question?

Comment: This one *clearly* has an answer over there: don't you read the answers you receive?

Comment: The interval there is $\int_0^{\infty}$.

Comment: What? $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 2):

[Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test): $\sin x$ has a bounded primitive and $\frac{1}{x}$ is decreasing to zero, hence $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx $ is conditionally convergent. It cannot be absolutely convergent since the mean value of $|\sin x|$ is $\frac{2}{\pi}$, so $\int_{1}^{M}\frac{|\sin x|}{x}\,dx $ behaves like $\frac{2}{\pi}\log M$ by integration by parts.